# Splitting a string in a list at its second space in Python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to reorder a name so that the last name is printed first, followed by a comma and the rest of the name. I feel like I am close, but all I seem to be able to do is split at the first space in the name. Since two of the names are already correctly ordered, I am appending them to the list as is. The only name that needs to be fixed is the first one, but I would like to have the code fix any error it finds.

Here is the code:

```
def name_refixer(name_list):
    fixed = []
    for name in name_list:
        if "," not in name:
            fix = name.split(" ",1)
            fix.reverse()
            fixed.append(fix)
        else:
            fixed.append(name)
    return fixed

name_list = ["David Andrew Joyner", "Hart, Melissa Joan", "Cyrus, Billy Ray"]
print(name_refixer(name_list))
```

This should be printing:
["Joyner, David Andrew", "Hart, Melissa Joan", "Cyrus, Billy Ray"]

However the closest I seem to be getting is:
[['Andrew Joyner', 'David'], 'Hart, Melissa Joan', 'Cyrus, Billy Ray']

I tried increasing the number in the split() to 2, but that only made each item in the string be separated by a comma instead of moving it to the second space.

I am still learning right now, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can take a look at the [`author_to_author_sort`](https://github.com/kovidgoyal/calibre/blob/v5.12.0/src/calibre/ebooks/metadata/__init__.py#L67) function in the calibre source. It's pretty legible. I'm not the author, but I know about it because I've made some changes to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option for you to achieve this would be to `split` all elements and then `join`. You can even avoid using `reverse`:

```
def name_refixer(name_list):
    fixed = []
    for name in name_list:
        if "," not in name:
            fix = name.split(" ")
            fix = fix[-1]+', '+(' ').join(fix[:len(fix)-1])
            fixed.append(fix)
        else:
            fixed.append(name)
    return fixed

name_list = ["David Andrew Joyner", "Hart, Melissa Joan", "Cyrus, Billy Ray"]
print(name_refixer(name_list))
```

In this code snippet notice, that I changed the way you use `split`.

`name.split(" ")` puts all words / names in a list (multiple words, multiple elements), as where `name.split(" ", 1)` puts the first word in the list as one element and the rest of the words as the second element of that list (multiple words, TWO elements).

Using `join` in this case is basically the opposite of using `split`. We put the words / elements of the list back into a string that is separated by a string that we give (' ' - a space). The first index used is `-1` because we want to get the last element as the last name. The second index used is `:len(fix)-1` as we want to get all elements except of the last element of the list as first name.

Comment: Thank you, could you help me understand what you added in?

Comment: Sure, I have just added a detailed description. Let me know if you need any more explanation. :)

Comment: Thank you! I will go over this and better my understanding

Answer (score 1):

Hey this should work:

```
name_list = ["David Andrew Joyner", "Hart, Melissa Joan", "Cyrus, Billy Ray"]
def name_reorder(name_list: list):
    l1 = []
    for i in name_list:
        name_split = i.split()
        mid_name_and_last_name =  name_split[1]+ ' ' +name_split[2]
        newstr = mid_name_and_last_name + ',' + name_split[0]
        l1.append(newstr)
name_reorder(name_list)
```

might not be the fastest way, if you have allot of data to feed
But should get the job done

Answer (score 1):

First, split the full name `fix = name.split(" ")`

then iterate over the list and append them to the `name` variable, if the index is equal to zero append a comma as well, if not, then just add a space

```
for i in range(len(fix)):
            if i == 0:
                name += fix[i] + ", "
            else:
                name += fix[i] + " "
```

then strip the `name` variable of leading and trailing spaces with the `strip` function before adding it to the `fixed` list

```
fixed.append(name.strip())
```

Here is the full code

```
def name_refixer(name_list):
    fixed = []
    for name in name_list:
        if "," not in name:
            fix = name.split(" ")
            fix.reverse()
            name = ""
            for i in range(len(fix)):
                if i == 0:
                    name += fix[i] + ", "
                else:
                    name += fix[i] + " "
            fixed.append(name.strip())
        else:
            fixed.append(name)
    return fixed

name_list = ["David Andrew Joyner", "Hart, Melissa Joan", "Cyrus, Billy Ray"]
print(name_refixer(name_list))
```